# ReactPlayer throwing "Video Unavailable" error on IE for youtube

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, youtube, youtube-iframe-api, react-player

I am getting the above error when using React Player (latest version). Youtube videos are showing 'video unavailable' in IE 11 but are running in chrome. React Player docs says, they support IE. I have added polyfills too as stated in doc but unable to run the video.
Also, have placed onError function in ReactPlayer which gives 150 as an error in it's argument.

Comment: Did you check whether the same video gets played if you directly try to access it using the IE browser? I suggest try to check it and if possible for you then try to provide some code example that may help to understand the issue in a better way. Also, try to check whether you are getting any error in the console or not. It gives some hint about the issue.

Comment: I try to make a test with the React-player in IE 11 and found that it is playing the Youtube videos without any issue. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/6Rim1iw). It can be possible that the issue is related to the code or to the video you are trying to playing. I suggest you just for testing purposes, create a new react app, and try to implement the react-player and see whether it is working or not. It can help to narrow down this issue. Let us know about your testing results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT hey thanks! Yeh that is happening on just my IE verion 11.504. I checked with multiple ppl having different versions of IE 11and the video is payable on IE too. Might be possible, an issue with FlashPlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with multiple ppl having different versions of IE 11and the video is payable on IE too. Most probably, an issue with FlashPlayer.